# Abundance in union closed families

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

For any finite set $S$ and every partition $S_1, \dots, S_n$ of $S$, let $P(S_1, \dots, S_n)$ be the family consisting of all possible unions of $S_1, \dots, S_n$. Clearly, $P(S_1, \dots, S_n)$ is a union-closed family and all elements of $S$ are *abundant* (present in at least half the sets of $P(S_1, \dots, S_n)$).

> Do all union-closed families such that all elements are abundant come from partitions?

Comment: No, the family $\{S\}$ has this property.

Comment: I meant, apart from this trivial one. I will edit the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I think all elements will be abundant when the basis sets partition the global set S. Want to know if there are any other situations where all elements are abundant.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what I think you mean.

Answer (score 3):

no, consider all subsets $A$ of a given set $S$ such that $|A|\geqslant 5$